# Python tkinter - Delete individual labels with associated buttons

Tags: button, tkinter, label

I am trying to enter text in a GUI and make labels out of the entered text. I am creating buttons next to the created labels. 
When these buttons are pressed, I want to delete the labels associated with those buttons. How can I do this?

Currently I have some code as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

chosenvarlabel = []
cancelbutton = []
label_relyPlacement = 0.4   # these allow variables to be displayed one below the other after #confirmation
label_relyIncrement = 0.0

root = tk.Tk()

IntroCanvas = tk.Canvas(height = 300, width = 300)
IntroCanvas.pack()

def cancel():
    pass
#     chosenvarlabel[cancelbutton[]].place_forget()  # unable to pass index here

def choose():
    global label_relyIncrement, chosenvarlabel, cancelbutton
    var1 = varentry1.get()
    var2 = varentry2.get()
    label_relyIncrement = label_relyIncrement + 0.1
    chosenvarlabel.append(tk.Label(root, text = var1 + " " + var2))
    chosenvarlabel[len(chosenvarlabel)-1].place(relx = 0.1, rely = label_relyPlacement + label_relyIncrement)
    cancelbutton.append(tk.Button(root, text = '   X', command = cancel))
    cancelbutton[len(chosenvarlabel)-1].place(relx = 0.6, rely = label_relyPlacement + label_relyIncrement)

varentry1 = tk.Entry(width = 6)
varentry1.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.2)

varentry2 = tk.Entry(width = 6)
varentry2.place(relx = 0.4, rely = 0.2)


myButton = tk.Button(root, text ='choose', command = choose)
myButton.place(relx = 0.6, rely = 0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

I am thinking since each button will be in the 'cancelbutton' list, if I pass the index of this button to the function 'cancel' somehow, the label of the same index in list chosenvarlabel will be deleted.

But I am unable to get the index using cancelbutton.index()

The cancelbutton list that is created is:

```
[<tkinter.Button object .!button2>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!button3>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!button4>]
```

But these elements cannot be accessed by 'index'. Why is that? How can I do this?

Thank you

R

Comment: You can pass the label reference to cancel() function.

Comment: How can I get the reference for a particular label without knowing it's index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If removing the associated label is the only task when the button is clicked, then the two lists are not necessary, you can just pass the label reference (and the button reference as well?) to `cancel()` function as below:

```py
def cancel(btn, lbl):
    # btn.destroy() # destroy the button as well???
    lbl.destroy()

def choose():
    global label_relyIncrement
    var1 = varentry1.get()
    var2 = varentry2.get()
    label_relyIncrement += 0.1
    lbl = tk.Label(root, text=var1+' '+var2)
    lbl.place(relx=0.1, rely=label_relyPlacement+label_relyIncrement)
    btn = tk.Button(root, text='X')
    btn.place(relx=0.6, rely=label_relyPlacement+label_relyIncrement)
    btn.config(command=lambda: cancel(btn, lbl))
```

Comment: This is very cool. Thank you! Can you please explain the last line of btn.config? How is the individual button associated with its label? What does the command=lambda do? I have read about lambda function but haven't understood it much.

Comment: Since I need the button reference, so I cannot set the `command` option when creating the button because the button does not exist at the moment.  After the button is created, I use the line `btn.config(command=...)` to set the command option.  `lambda` is anonymous function.